# std::array: Why is there no warning or error on `at(-2)`?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-warnings, stdarray

The book says that `std::array` is safer and simpler than other methods of the assignment.

Here's my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<array>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    array<int, 5> a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    a.at(-2) = 100;
    cout << a[-2] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why is there no warning or error in this code?

Comment: `a.at(-2)=100;` there should be an exception since size_type is unsigned https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at

Comment: I get the expected exception when running this code: https://ideone.com/ROoqpm

Comment: Did you actually run it or compile it? It's not supposed to throw a compiler error.

Comment: Perhaps you're expecting a compilation error, but it will throw an exception at runtime. If your book does not explain this, you need a better book.

Answer (score 2):

The `at` member function does a runtime check, and the `operator[]` does no check (this is intentional design).

You can do compile-time checking by using `get`:

```
#include <array>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    array<int, 5> a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    get<1>(a) = 100;  // ok
    get<-2>(a) = 100; // error
    get<5>(a) = 100;  // error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`std::array::at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at) accepts an argument of `size_type` which usually is defined in terms of some `unsinged` type e.g. `std::size_t` / `unsigned long`.

The actual argument `-2` is of `signed int` type which is [implicitly converted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) to `size_type` while passing to `at()` and becomes a valid `size_type` number; but, only a wrapped-around one. See [example](https://godbolt.org/z/JPAkHX).

By default, you don't get a compiler warning/error for implicit conversion. You have to look for your compiler options like [GCC's](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) `-Wconversion`, `Wsign-conversion`, etc. to enable these settings. In your case on GCC, `-Wsign-conversion` will warn you about these conversions; and, in combination with `-Werror`, these warnings will become errors.

Observe the compiler output of your code with compiler flags `-std=c++11 -Werror -Wsign-conversion` ([live](https://godbolt.org/z/kQ_DUn)):

**Compiler output:**

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':

<source>:6:10: error: unsigned conversion from 'int' to 'std::array<int, 5>::size_type' {aka 'long unsigned int'} changes value from '-2' to '18446744073709551614' [-Werror=sign-conversion]

    6 |     a.at(-2)=100;

      |          ^~

<source>:7:13: error: unsigned conversion from 'int' to 'std::array<int, 5>::size_type' {aka 'long unsigned int'} changes value from '-2' to '18446744073709551614' [-Werror=sign-conversion]

    7 |     cout<<a[-2]<<endl;

      |             ^~

cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Here's another [example](https://godbolt.org/z/HSeDFJ) that simulates the same thing.

---

And, in `at()`, the passed argument is validated against the array size. Here, you will get a runtime exception of type [std::out_of_range](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) as described by the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at):

> If `pos` is not within the range of the container, an exception of type `std::out_of_range` is thrown.

You may look at its implementation provided by your compiler if you're so inclined to.

And, when you use an invalid index with [subscript operator `[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/operator_at) e.g. `a[-2]` where `-2` to `size_type` conversion returns into a wrapped-around value, the result will be an out-of-bounds access and will cause an [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Hope this explanation helps!

Answer (score 0):

accessing invalid `std::array` element with `.at` will cause exception handler to throw run time error regardless of the case if you compile and run it in the release or debug.

Only time you would not see an error is when you use the  member access operators `[]` as you have done in your example in release mode.

```
cout<<a[-2]<<endl;
```

in debug mode you will only get the out of bounds error after compiling and running. In release mode, it's undefined behaviour.

This is also why using `.at` is recommended instead of directly accessing the elements with `[]` operator.

Comment: question was about compile time: why there is no warring?

Comment: all I'm seeing is why there is no error. to have no error at all when running [] must be used instead of .at in release mode basically. that's what I tried to answer.

Comment: `a[-2]` results in undefined behavior. Full stop. Undefined behavior means that the language definition doesn't tell you what the program does. That has nothing to do with compiler settings; anything that the compiler does is okay, since the behavior is undefined. And note that `.at` is not "recommended"; it's sometimes useful, and often pointless.

Comment: @PeteBecker a[-2] will throw an assertion error because its an std:: array in debug mode. its caught because of how std::array does the assertion check. so how is that an undefined behaviour?  I'm not going to delve into why .at is recommended. perhaps I should have clarified there is a performance catch. I see your point if we end up accessing an array element with .at within same call multiple times though.

Comment: @Yucel_K -- `a[-2]` **might** check for out of bounds. It is not required to. Again: the behavior is undefined. There's nothing more you can say about it, unless your compiler **documents** what it does, and that, of course, only applies to that compiler.